# Running in DTS in Deployed ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net-2010

I have created a web application that runs a DTS remotely from a sql server 2000.
I made it worked in the visual studio environment but when i deploy it,
it doesn't work and the error message says :
 **DataPump_Task Failed.**

I am not sure about my findings but...
does the problem has something to do with my IIS settings?

I am running IIS 7 on windows 7.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

When you execute a DTS Package from an ASP page, the package executes in the security context of the Web site visitor, which may be that of the Windows user (if the web site is configured for Basic or NT Authentication) or of the Anonymous account.

The package does not execute in the security context of the user ID supplied to load the package from SQL Server. Therefore, it is important to make sure that the account executing the package has appropriate Windows permissions to all resources that the package may use, such as disk files, DLLs, or other drivers (for import/export operations) especially when the Web site is configured for Anonymous access.

If a package works in the DTS designer and works from other client applications, but fails from Web applications, troubleshooting should begin with permissions issues.

For additional information about determining which Windows account will be used to execute the DTS package, see this article http://support.microsoft.com/kb/269074/EN-US

Comment: I found that answer already on google. But i assume that is not the answer and the application i've been looking for.